# SELECT query from 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `matches` that I want to get from it the users that has the best score:

```
SELECT userId,SUM(score) AS score FROM `matches` GROUP BY userId ORDER BY score DESC
```

This output 2 columns `userId` and `score`. Good.
Now I have a `users` table, and I want to have a more detailed output of that `userId`. For example, I want to have: `userId-firstName-lastName-phone-address-score`. Is this possible with a simple sql query ?
Thank you.

Comment: Look into [MySQL JOINs](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/).

Comment: Yes use join on `users` table

Comment: Look into the `JOIN` syntax in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT userId, firstName, lastName, phone, address, SUM(score) AS score FROM matches join users on matches.user_id = users.user_id GROUP BY userId ORDER BY score DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much Vishal ! Accept in 8 minutes !

Answer (score 3):

You could just `JOIN` the tables like this:

```
SELECT 
    matches.userId,
    SUM(matches.score) AS score,
    users.firstName,
    users.lastName,
    users.phone,
    users.address
FROM 
    `matches`
    JOIN users
        ON `matches`.userId=users.userId
GROUP BY 
    matches.userId,
    users.firstName,
    users.lastName,
    users.phone,
    users.address 
ORDER BY 
    score DESC
```

Reference:

- [13.2.8.2 JOIN Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, simply use a [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) statement, like:

```
SELECT m.userId, SUM(m.score) AS score, u.firstName, u.lastName FROM `matches` AS m
INNER JOIN `users` AS u ON u.userId = m.userId
GROUP BY userId ORDER BY score DESC
```